# tmux: Automatically hide pane on focus loss

Tags: terminal, tmux

I'd like to automatically hide a tmux pane as soon as it looses focus. Currently, I use 'Prefix+z' to manually maximize the current pane, hiding the unfocused pane. However, whenever I require to switch a little more often between panes, it becomes cumbersome to manually maximize. Is there a way to automatically hide unfocused panes?

I know this question exists: [Tmux: Auto-hide panel when it loses focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790781/tmux-auto-hide-panel-when-it-loses-focus)
However, it does not answer my question.

Comment: If you always want the pane in focus to be maximized, why not just have multiple windows with 1 pane each?

Comment: @jeremysprofile I use vim with tmux. Sometimes its useful to see the terminal output. If auto hide would be enabled, I would just "unhide" it to see the terminal.

Comment: I don't understand your question. There is always only one pane that is in focus. If you automatically hide panes that are not in focus, you will always only see one pane. This is equivalent to having one pane per window and switching windows.

Comment: I want to have one pan in focus most of the time, with the option of blending in the second (containing the terminal).

Comment: You can remap your pane-swapping command to be pane-swapping and zooming at the same time. then you would manually unzoom to see the other panes if desired.

Comment: This is something I have been thinking of as well. However I use tmux also for other applications, where this behavior would interfere.

Answer (score 2):

You could put resizep -Z in the key bindings you use to change pane and window (you will likely need a check if it is already focused - you can use if-shell -F and the window_zoomed format for this).

Or maybe you could use the focus-in hook but I suspect that will be harder to get working.